# function that run always even when app is not on foreground in angular ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, tracking

i want to know how i make a function in a service executes always - if a condition is true (based on api response ) - even if the app is not in foreground in angular ionic.
the function calls capacitor geolocation watch position to track and save user coords.
do i need to make service worker ? or there is some other solution
if i call it in app.component.ts does it still executing when app is not in foreground

i tried puttting the function call in app.component but i noticed it not always executed

Comment: you can use background mode. https://github.com/capacitor-community/background-geolocation

Answer (score -1):

No there is not, Apple does not allow this, especially on hybrid apps. There may be plugins out there that were made before the policies changed, but in there readme, they state to use at your own risk and you app will not be allowed in the app stores.